# Exception Handling and flow

Tags: java

I have this method and for the sql query I'm using and the particular survey the query returns no rows. So 'questions' should be empty and a EmptyResultDataAccessException should be thrown (I verified that logger.warn(msg) is executed in my use case.) This exception should then be caught in the following method.

```
    private void addSurveyQuestions(Survey survey)
        throws CustomException, DataAccessException {

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

    //Build some sql query

    List<SurveyQuestion> questions =
            getJdbcTemplate().query(sql.toString(), new Object[] { survey.getQuestionnaireKey() },
                    new SurveyQuestionRowMapper());

    // This should never happen, but just in case
    if (questions == null || questions.size() == 0) {
        String msg = "Expected at least 1 question for survey " + survey.getQuestionnaireKey();
        logger.warn(msg);
        throw new EmptyResultDataAccessException(msg, 1);
    }

    // Loop through all the questions - populate the multiple choice answers and add questions to survey
    for (SurveyQuestion q : questions) {
            //some stuff
        }
        survey.addSurveyQuestion(q);
    }
}
```

In this method for my use case the sql query will return one row and so 'survey' is not null and addSurveyQuestions(survey) will be executed which should throw a EmptyResultDataAccessException. This then should be caught and the method return null. However I never see logger.info("No surveys  for survey " + surveyKey); being executed and it appears a Survey object with a empty surveyQuestions List is being returned (Info level logging is enabled).

```
public Survey getSurvey(Long surveyKey) throws CustomException {

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

    //some sql query

    try {
        // Get top level container object
        Survey survey =
                getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql.toString(), new Object[] {surveyKey },
                        new SurveyRowMapper());

        // Add the questions and answers
        if (survey != null) {
            addSurveyQuestions(survey);
        }

        return survey;

    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException empty) {

        // This is ok,no surveys.
        logger.info("No surveys  for survey " + surveyKey);
        return null;

    } catch (DataAccessException dae) {
        String msg = "some message " + surveyKey;
        logger.error(msg);
        throw new CustomException(msg + ", Exception: " + dae.getMessage(), dae);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the EmptyResultDataAccessException isn't being caught?

Comment: Why don't you simply check if the returned result set is empty?

Comment: for debugging, try catching a generic `Execption` and seeing if it is being caught

Comment: I would catch Throwable (in case there's a NPE being thrown) instead of Exception.  Also, print some debug output before returning survey to ensure you are not reaching that point.